# Traefik - TLS Certificates for multiple subdomains does not work

Tags: ssl-certificate, traefik

I am using traefik as a reverse proxy for my infra. I want to deploy with docker compose, a stack like that :

- Traefik : Reverse proxy
- Nextcloud
- Redis : Nextcloud cache
- Postgres : Nnextcloud Db
- Gogs : VCS
- Postgres : Gogs Db

My compose is the following :

```
version: "3.3"

volumes:
    nextcloud-www:
        driver: local
    nextcloud-db:
        driver: local
    nextcloud-redis:
        driver: local
    letsencrypt:
        driver: local
    gogs-data:
        driver: local
    gogs-db:
        driver: local

services:
    #Traefik
    traefik:
        image: traefik
        container_name: traefik
        restart: unless-stopped
        command:
            - "--log.level=DEBUG"
            - "--api.insecure=true"
            - "--providers.docker=true"
            - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
            - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
            - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
            - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
            - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=myemail@email.email"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
            - 8080:8080
        networks:
            - nextcloud
            - gogs
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
        labels:
            traefik.enable: true

    # Nextcloud
    nextcloud:
        image: nextcloud
        container_name: nextcloud
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - nextcloud
        depends_on:
            - nextcloud_redis
            - nextcloud_db
        labels:
            traefik.enable: true
            traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.middlewares: nextcloud,nextcloud_redirect
            traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.tls.certresolver: myresolver
            traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.rule: Host(`cloud.mydomain.fr`)
            traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.customFrameOptionsValue: ALLOW-FROM https://mydomain.fr
            traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.contentSecurityPolicy: frame-ancestors 'self' mydomain.fr *.mydomain.fr
            traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.stsSeconds: 155520011
            traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.stsIncludeSubdomains: true
            traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud.headers.stsPreload: true
            traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud_redirect.redirectregex.regex: /.well-known/(card|cal)dav
            traefik.http.middlewares.nextcloud_redirect.redirectregex.replacement: /remote.php/dav/
        environment:
            POSTGRES_HOST: nextcloud_db
            POSTGRES_DB: nextcloud
            POSTGRES_USER: nextcloud
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER: dimitri_admin
            NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
            REDIS_HOST: nextcloud_redis
            NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS: cloud.mydomain.fr
            TRUSTED_PROXIES: 172.18.0.0/16
        volumes:
            - nextcloud-www:/var/www/html

    # Nextcloud Db
    nextcloud_db:
        image: postgres
        container_name: nextcloud_db
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - nextcloud
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: nextcloud
            POSTGRES_USER: nextcloud
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
            - nextcloud-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    # Nextcloud Redis
    nextcloud_redis:
        image: redis
        container_name: nextcloud_redis
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - nextcloud
        volumes:
            - nextcloud-redis:/var/lib/redis

    # Gogs
    gogs:
        image: gogs/gogs-rpi
        container_name: gogs
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - gogs
        depends_on:
            - gogs_db
        labels:
            traefik.enable: true
            traefik.http.services.gogs.loadbalancer.server.port: 3000
            traefik.http.routers.gogs.tls.certresolver: myresolver
            traefik.http.routers.gogs.rule: Host(`git.mydomain.fr`)

        environment:
            # Postgres config
            POSTGRES_HOST: gogs_db
            POSTGRES_DB: gogs
            POSTGRES_USER: gogs
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
            - gogs-data:/data

    # Gogs database
    gogs_db:
        image: postgres
        container_name: gogs_db
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - gogs
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: gogs
            POSTGRES_USER: gogs
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
            - gogs-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

# Networks
networks:
    nextcloud:
        external: true
    gogs:
        external: true
```

The problem is the following :
The certificates are not generated for my websites.

How can i do it ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Use a wildcard...
https://docs.traefik.io/https/acme/#wildcard-domains

Option 2: Multiple certs...
Make multiple certresolvers and cert files (1 per domain) and use those in the services.

```yaml
services:
    traefik:
        command:
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver1.acme.httpchallenge=true"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver1.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver1.acme.email=myemail@email.email"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver1.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/domain1.json"

            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver2.acme.httpchallenge=true"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver2.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver2.acme.email=myemail@email.email"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver2.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/domain2.json"

    nextcloud:
        labels:
            traefik.http.routers.nextcloud.tls.certresolver: myresolver1

    gogs:
        labels:
            traefik.http.routers.gogs.tls.certresolver: myresolver2
```